# Linq SELECT AS and CONCAT

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, select, concatenation

I have been given a SQL query that I need to translate into LINQ, that's not a problem but there are a couple of items that I need help with in this particular query and those are the selecting column name as '' and also the concatination.  Here is the query in question:

```
SELECT vessel_idx, 
       vessel_name, 
       spotlist_dp, 
       spotlist_bhp,
       spotlist_deck, 
       spotlist_bp, 
       spotlist_oilrec, 
       spotlist_fifi, 
       spotlist_rov,
       '' AS fixture_charterer,
       '' AS fixture_work,
CONCAT( fixture_charterer ,
        ' ', 
        mid(fixture_start,9,2),
        '/',
        mid(fixture_start,6,2)) AS next_charterer_info, 
        '' AS fixture_location,
        '0000-00-00 00:00:00' AS  fixture_stop, 
        '' AS fixture_note 
FROM tbl_vessels

WHERE vessel_type='AHTS'

AND current_location_spotlist_id = 2
AND fixture_start > '2016-02-12 08:30:00'
AND vessel_status = 'PPT'

ORDER BY fixture_stop
```

The usual stuff like AND, WHERE etc I can deal with it's purly these sections I'm struggling with.  The selecting column as '':

```
SELECT '' AS fixture_charterer,
       '' AS fixture_work,
```

and the concatination

```
CONCAT( fixture_charterer ,
        ' ', 
        mid(fixture_start,9,2),
        '/',
        mid(fixture_start,6,2)) AS next_charterer_info, 
        '' AS fixture_location,
        '0000-00-00 00:00:00' AS  fixture_stop, 
        '' AS fixture_note
```

Many thanks

Comment: Why are you struggling with it? What is your attempt?

Answer (score 0):

SELECT AS is represented as:

```
var demo = from vessel in db.tbl_vessels
         select new {
           fixture_charterer = "", 
           fixture_work = ""
         };
```

CONCAT is:

```
var demo = from vessel in db.tbl_vessels
         select new {
           fixture_note = fixture_charterer + " " + next_charterer_info 
         };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select constants like `""` easily:

```
var q = from v in ....
        ....
        select new 
        {
           ...,
           fixture_charterer = "",
           fixture_work = "",
           next_charterer_info = 
               (v.fixture_charterer ?? "") + " " 
             + (v.fixture_start == null ? "" : v.fixture_start.Substring(8,2)) 
        };
```